# How to get every element of any depth in an xml having the id attribute?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing a program which updates id attribute values in an xml data,in actionscript 3.
Any 2 id s must not duplicate to each other even they are of items of different tag names.
Please give answers how to get the list of every such element that it has the id attribute .

Than you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you need. But I may give some advice on xml nodes and setting unique ids.

For example take this xml structure as var myXML:XML.

<root>
   <node uid="" name="node1">
         <node uid="" name="node1.1"/>
         <node uid="" name="node1.2"/>
   </node>
   <node uid="" name="node2">
         <node uid="" name="node2.1">
              <node uid="" name="node2.1.2"/>
         </node>
  </node>
</root>

public function updateUIDs():void
{
    var allNodeItems:XMLList = myXML..node; 
    var len:int = allNodeItems.length();
    var i:int;
    var node:XML;
    var uid:String;

`for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
     node   = allNodeItems[i] as XML;
      uid    = UIDUtil.createUID();

      trace("Setting uid=" + uid+" to node: "+node.@name);
     node.@uid = uid;
 }`

}

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is the short version:

```
var list : XMLList = xml..*.(@id != null);
for each (var node:XML in list) node.@id = createUniqueID();
```